# CMake: source_group for all subdirectories

Tags: cmake

I want to use cmakes `source_group` with regex. As long as the command is in the same file as my target everything works fine, but I want to set the `source_group` in my main CMakeLists.txt file, because I have many sub_directories. Is it possible to set a cmake config to pass it down to my subdirectories?

example

```
source_group("Source Files" REGULAR_EXPRESSION ".*\\.cpp")
source_group("Header Files" REGULAR_EXPRESSION ".*\\.h")
source_group("Ui Files" REGULAR_EXPRESSION ".*\\.ui")
source_group("Resource Files" REGULAR_EXPRESSION ".*\\.qrc")

add_subdirectory(src)
```

Greetings
Tonka